# React showing different locally and online

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code

```
 <BarChart
    xAxis={[{data: xAxis, scaleType: 'band'}]}
    margin={{bottom: 35, right: 280}}
    series={graph.datas}
    slotProps={{
        legend: {
            direction: 'column',
            position: { vertical: 'middle', horizontal: 'right' },
            padding: 0,
            itemMarkWidth: 15,
            itemMarkHeight: 10,
            markGap: 3,
            itemGap: 2
        }
    }}
    width={700}
    height={320}
 />
```

After adding the slotProps section
Locally I have something like this:
[Locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOpjD.png)

But when the merge was sent to prod it looks like this:
[Online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxWHI.png)

I already did npm run build on prod and the changes were made, but only the way it is showing is not correct.
Can someone help please?
By the way I am using MUI X v6.11.0 library

Tried to find the solution but can't find it.

EDIT:
I found out that online I have this added in my css after doing yarn deploy:admin
[Online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkYQN.png)

And offline I don't  have anything
[Offline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBdki.png)

It seems that online the transform class that is being added is moving all the items to the left when I do yarn deploy:admin

Comment: It's going to be very tough for us to help you debug difference between your local dev environment and a hosted environment. Have you done all the standard things: Clearing browser/CDN caches, a clean build, making sure the source data is identical, etc?

Comment: I have tried to clear the browser cache, not the CDN.

Comment: @DBS Also, I did clean build and data is generic, so it is not the problem on the back, its just really on the front, the way it is showing.

Comment: This situation is often due to `StrictMode` and the result of the effect code are not as expected.

Comment: @Jay I have updated the question, it's not StrictMode